# ArgumentError : Missing Keyword when Init a Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple pattern result class to init on controller, everything works well on ruby 2.3.x <= 2.7.x, I try on ruby 3.0.1 with Rails 6.1.4.
My project structure looks like :

```
app/
..controllers
....api
......v1
.........files_controllers.rb
..jobs
..mailers
..serializers
..services
....v1
......list_result.rb
..value_objects
```

A simple pattern result class I put on services directory

```
module V1
    class ListResult
        attr_reader :status,
                    :status_message,
                    :data,
                    :meta

        SUCCESS = 1

        def initialize(status_message:, data:, meta:)
            @status = SUCCESS
            @status_message = status_message
            @data = data
            @meta = meta
        end

        def success?
            @status == SUCCESS
        end

    end
end
```

And try to in on controller looks like :

```
V1::ListResult.new(status_message: "", data: [], meta: {})
```

I'm getting this error :

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: status_message, data, meta)
from /app/services/v1/list_result.rb:10:in `initialize
```

but it's works on rails console

```
3.0.1 :001 > V1::ListResult.new(status_message: "", data: [], meta: {})
 => #<V1::ListResult:0x00007f8d3dbaa730 @data=[], @meta={}, @status=1, @status_message="">
```

irb console

```
3.0.1 :001 > class MyClass
3.0.1 :002 >   def initialize(status_message:, data:, meta:)
3.0.1 :003 >     puts "#{status_message} #{data} #{meta}"
3.0.1 :004 >   end
3.0.1 :005 > end
3.0.1 :006 > MyClass.new(status_message: "", data: [], meta: {})
 [] {}
```

I've [read about Separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/), but I confused why it's work on rails console and irb console only?

Comment: Ar you sure you are not sending it like this `V1::ListResult.new({status_message: "", data: [], meta: {}})` or rather `a = {status_message: "", data: [], meta: {}}; V1::ListResult.new(a)`? In either case you need to double splat the Hash to convert those to kwargs e.g. `V1::ListResult.new(**a)`

Comment: @engineersmnky I tried that before, yes that's works, but my question is why on rails console and irb console working well for my case on OP

Comment: In the console you are actually passing keywords not a `Hash`. In your code you are passing an `Object` as a positional argument e.g. `V1::ListResult.new(status_message: "", data: [], meta: {})` (3 keyword arguments) vs `V1::ListResult.new(params)` (1 positional argument)

Comment: Is this a Rails app? Tried to restart spring?